# Make two functions use the same number (generated by findRandom) in Typescript

Tags: typescript, random

The problem now I'm facing is functions call findRandom twice and get two different value at the end. How to make findRandom randomly pick a number and store it at storeRandom where the number will be unchanged.

Expected result: all the functions share the same number or value.

```
getRandom = a.findRandom(0,1);
storeRandom = getRandom; 

functionA() {
   if (storeRandom == 0){
       console.log("0");
   }
}

functionB(){
    if (storeRandom == 1){
        console.log("1");
    }
}
```

Comment: `=` is an assignment operator, `===` is a comparison operator

Comment: Please consider editing this code to constitute a [mcve] as described in [ask].  Ideally it would be something you could drop into a standalone IDE like [the Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/) and it would demonstrate your issue.  As it stands you have undeclared variables like `getRandom`, `storeRandom`, and `a`.  Good luck!

Comment: @jcalz getRandom, storeRandom, and a. is just a example variable name that I declare, it won't affect the entire flow of the code

Comment: The example code [is full of errors](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/OYUwLgSghgdgJgewLYAIC8KoDoBmBLeaeZACgAYAaARgEoBuAWACgBnMBAJxCMVQ1EixedFCmbMcAVxgBjMHgQwAgiRooA3s1Eo8OFCTaduQ5OgxkamptpszFLBABsQWRwmAkARGU-0togF9mIKYJaTkFGAAhVSsbXX1DLh5TNAxaOJttOxgHZ1d3LypfRmttEICgA).  If you want help, you should consider fixing it.  I'm not even sure what your question is, unfortunately.  Is it "can I call a function once, save its result in a variable, and use the result multiple times later?"  If so, the answer is "yes".  But without a clear question and useful example code I can't advise more.

Answer (score 0):

What i understand what you need is - private function constant/ internal function state. You need to somehow store in both function the same one value. In functional programming state can be easily implemented by [closures](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures).

> A closure is the combination of a function bundled together (enclosed) with references to its surrounding state (the lexical environment). In other words, a closure gives you access to an outer function’s scope from an inner function. In JavaScript, closures are created every time a function is created, at function creation time.

We can by using closures pass to both functions closures the same value. Consider:

```
// makeFunctionA creates a function with lexical scope containing v
function makeFunctionA(v: number) {
  // very important returning a function
  return () => {
    console.log(v);
    return v;
  }
}
function makeFunctionB(v: number) {
  return () => {
    console.log(v);
    return v;
  }
}

const randomNumber = 1 // here call some random generator, 1 here only for as an example
const functionA = makeFunctionA(randomNumber); // make function with closure containing value
const functionB = makeFunctionB(randomNumber); // make function with closure containing value

functionA() === functionB() // the equation is true both share the same value
```

After that both functions can be called in any place of the codebase, but the value visible for them will stay the same.